# Codeigniter 3 - pagination from array - links not showing up

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm building in CI3 and pulling data from a MSSQL database (no offset, are you kidding?), so i've been force to paginate from an array (see [How to get CI pagination to work with a array();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180938/how-to-get-ci-pagination-to-work-with-a-array)). Everything is working, I can manually add digits to the url (segment) and get the required results but i can't get the pagination links to show up at all.
 I have been through the other similar questions on this site but none seem to relate.
Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

The **Route** -   `$route['orders/:num'] = 'orders/index';`

The **Model** just pulls rows

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        // Load Pagination Library
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        // Get results from MSSQL database
        $pages = $this->orders_m->get_orders($this->session->customer_code);
        // Initiate chunks array to create pages
        $chunks = array();
        // Offset used to index of chunk arrays to display relevent results, default to 1 if segment is missing.
        $offset = $this->uri->segment(2,1);
        // How many items to show per page
        $limit = 10; 
        // an index you can use to find offsets for pagination
        $index=0;
        // count the retured results from the query
        $count = count($pages);

    // loop through the pages array in chunks, and create
    // an index or offset you can query from 
    foreach(array_chunk($pages, $limit) as $page){
        $index++;
        $chunks[$index] = $page; // build your array 
    }
    // add to a data array to be passed to the view
    $data['orders'] = $chunks[$offset]; 
    // Set config options for the pagination class
    $config = array(
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'orders/',
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2,
        $config['total_rows'] = $count,
        $config['per_page'] = $limit,
        $config['display_pages'] = TRUE
    );
    // Initialise the pagination class
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    // Add the links to a data variable to be sent to the view
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links(); // FAIL

    // The 'why the fuck isn't it working' test procedure

    print_r($data['links'])."<br>"; //FAIL;

    print_r($config)."<br>"; //OK

    echo $count."<br>"; //OK

    echo $offset."<br>"; //OK

    echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r($data['orders']); //OK
    echo "</pre>";    
        //$this->load->view('elements/header');
        //$this->load->view('orders', $data);
        //$this->load->view('elements/footer');    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out the answer. As it isn't pulling rows from the database, instead it's using chunks from the array, per page needed to be one, as one chunk = 10 rows.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('orders');
        $config['total_rows'] = ceil($count/$limit);
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = 5;
```

Ended up ditching this method anyway and used datatables to manipulate the data and perform the pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added pagination view in your view file .Please check and add these lines:-

```
 <div class="pagination" style="float:right; margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;">
        <ul>
            <?php echo $pagination_links; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I should be able to see the links stored in the variable $data['links'] prior to sending it to the view file though, it's an empty string at the moment.